# Is there a term for a word that is only used if paired with another word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for a word that is only used if paired with another word?

For example "dulcet", (Dulcet tones), or "inclement".

Comment: Do you mean paired only with a specific word (which doesn't apply to your examples), or always paired with some word, any word (which I don't think applies to your examples either)? They are both adjectives, so one would expect a corresponding noun somewhere in the sentence, but not necessary right next to them.

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is probably **[fossil word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_word)**:

> A fossil word is a word that is broadly obsolete but remains in current use due to its presence within an idiom. Fossil status can also occur for word senses and for phrases.

Wikipedia gives the examples of “eke out” and “to and fro”.

Neither of your words is exclusively paired with a single word though. *Inclement* almost always collocates with *weather* but can also be found in “inclement conditions”. And *dulcet* is also found in “dulcet voice”. (Both of these examples and more can be found using the collocation feature of [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) or its sister corpora.)

Comment: Further, you might (possibly) say "The voice I heard was dulcet" or "Weather conditions were inclement".